# linux + rcp rsh post configuration after installing rsh package

Tags: linux, remote-access, rsh

I installed by yum the latest rsh package ( because on my linux machine rsh and rcp binaries not exists )

```
 # yum install rsh
```

so I verified by:

```
rpm -qa | grep -i rsh

 rsh-0.17-60.el6.x86_64
 rsh-server-0.17-17.x86_64
```

then I reboot my linux machine - red-hat 6.4

and try to do  the following tests

```
# rsh localhost
  connect to address ::1: Connection refused
  Trying 127.0.0.1...
```

.

```
 rcp localhost:/etc/hosts /tmp
 rcmd: localhost: Connection reset by peer
```

in my machine .rhosts and /etc/hosts.equiv not exists ( not sure if rsh installation VIA yum should create them ? )

please advice what the next steps that I need to do in order to solve this issue ?

Comment: Is there a good reason for using rsh (and not ssh)?

Comment: I not have ssh server on remote machine -(:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, I've never used rsh (only SSH). I am under the impression the rsh server is not started / listening to connection properly.

1. Is the server process running

> ps aux | grep rsh

Note: "ps aux" will list all processes. You should have a line with "rsh".

2. Is the process listening to TCP/514

> ss -t -l

Note: Display all tcp socket which are listening. You should have one for port 514. I use "ss" which is the replacement of netstat. I am not sure if it is installed on your Red Hat.

Finally, here is a tutorial I found. It seems like you might need to edit the configuration file to enable the daemon.

http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/setup-remote-shell-access-on-centos-6-rhel-6.html#axzz36sMYbceE

Comment: I get this from my machine --> ps aux | grep rsh
root      2172  0.0  0.0 103236   860 pts/0    S+   14:51   0:00 grep rsh

Comment: btw - I was in burn before 10 years

Comment: maihabunash: The output you have is the "grep" command running with the argument rsh. If you only have this line, when you don't have a process rsh started. 
Check the link I posted... it should be helpful.

Comment: I do all the steps according to the link and still not have the proccess